# Moq Unit test working on windows but not on Mono build server

Tags: c#, mono, servicestack, moq, teamcity-8.0

I have unit test for a ServiceStack based service that passes on my windows workstation, however the TeamCity server which is on ubuntu/mono doesn't pass - other tests do run however, just one in particular.

This fails

```
    [Test]
    public void Post_Valid_Property_Should_Return_HttpStatus_OK()
    {
        var manager = new Mock<IRedisClientsManager>();
        var redisClient = new Mock<IRedisClient>();
        var redisTypedClient = new Mock<IRedisTypedClient<Share.Property.Model.Property>>();
        manager.Setup(t => t.GetClient()).Returns(redisClient.Object);
        redisClient.Setup(t => t.As<Share.Property.Model.Property>()).Returns(redisTypedClient.Object);
        var sut = new SomeService(manager.Object);
        var result = sut.Post(new PropertySaveRequest {Property = new Share.Property.Model.Property { Id = 1, OwnerId = 2 } });
        Assert.That(result.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));

    }
```

Other tests not using mocks pass fine eg.

```
    [Test]
    public void Post_Invalid_Property_Should_Throw_Exception()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer()
            .Install(new PropertyInstaller());
        var service = _container.Resolve<IPropertyService>();
        Assert.That(() => service.Post(new PropertySaveRequest { Property = new Share.Property.Model.Property{Id=-11, OwnerId = -14} }),
            Throws.Exception.TypeOf<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>());

    }
```

[TeamCity log](https://gist.github.com/orbitalmedia/dea71f5c90191dd5211f)

My guess is the error is Moq related, as the other test can use Castle IOC without throwing.

Test(s) failed. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Any ideas appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034341/system-collections-generic-keynotfoundexception-with-mono-but-not-microsofts Not surprising at all, as not every tool works for Mono.

Comment: Rhino Mocks same error - know of any mocking libs that work on mono?

Comment: Then you can find https://www.google.com/search?q=Mocking+framework+mono&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: What a strange response...